# How to Install magento on WampServer for Localhost?

Tags: php, ajax, magento

As I am configuring Magento on WampServer for localhost I am getting an error as
Please enter a valid URL. Protocol is required (http://, https:// or ftp://)
as Mysql version

```
* Server: localhost (MySQL host info: localhost via TCP/IP)
* Server version: 5.1.36-community
* Protocol version: 10
* User: root@localhost
* MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

and webserver is

```
* Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0
* MySQL client version: mysqlnd 5.0.5-dev - 081106 - $Revision: 1.3.2.27 $
* PHP extension: mysqli
```

phpMyAdmin
    * Version information: 3.2.0.
as I also made changes in validation.js file
made validate-url to return true
but still not working for me
can anybody help me out for setting my localhost
Thanks in advance

Comment: did the installation gave you any error / tip about localhost?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "localhost" you can use "127.0.0.1" which Magento prefers because it has periods.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer these links for magento installation

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/magento_installation_guide

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-installation-guide

Comment: even though it gives error in base url. Please enter a valid URL. Protocol is required (http://, https:// or ftp://)

Comment: Please go to this path  C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc  in this folder add the line in hosts file    10.0.0.2 www.localhost.com